# Version of JUnit differs between runtime and compile time?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I have a huge problem with JUnit tests suddenly not running anymore. The issue is that i use TemporaryFolder.newFile(), which is a relatively new method, and although everything compiles fine, at runtime i get a NoSuchMethodError. From the commandline via maven/tycho, everything works as expected.

But what i really don't understand is this: As far as i can see, the only available JUnit version is 4.11, so i don't get how a different version would be possible to use at runtime?

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder tempFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

private File prepareInputFile(...) throws ... {
    File inputFile = tempFolder.newFile();
...
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "at runtime", as compared to "via maven"? Are you (failing) running tests in an IDE that perhaps supplies it's own version of JUnit?

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup Yes, by "at runtime" i mean "when running as JUnit test in the Eclipse IDE". By "compile time" i mean "when compiling inside the IDE".

Comment: in pom.xml when defining the junit dependency - do you specify a version? what version of java do you use (java -version)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here is what happened and how i finally diagnosed it:

My test bundle is a fragment of my project bundle. One of the bundles on which my project bundle depends includes a version of JUnit, which is older than the one that is part of my target platform. At compile time in Eclipse (and when tycho is involved), the target platform version (4.11.0) is used. But when i run it as JUnit test through Eclipse, the JUnit classes get resolved by the other bundle (which includes JUnit 4.8.2 apparently).

How did i find it?
Through going to the class file of the JUnit Runners that appear in the stack traces.

Solution?
No really satisfying solution for "Run as JUnit-test" yet, using the older API solves this problem but just shows others (Hamcrest matchers subclassing newer hamcrest API cause trouble. "Run as Plug-in test" gave me problems, too, but i solved this now by removing all plugins from the run-configuration and only adding the dependencies.